# Visualising Work Item hierarchy and Test Cases in one view

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps we need to visualize the parent-child links of Work Items together with their associated Test Cases (through the tested-by links).

With WIQL, the parent-child links can be visualized with tree queries, the tested-by links with dependency queries.

But how do I visualise both parent-child and tested-by links in 1 hierarchical structure? We need such an overview to see which Work Items have associated Test Cases, and at the same time their place in the Work Item hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tested the different types of query "Tree of work items" and "work items and directly links", and the results were the same as yours.

Since the query is based on types. Currently there is no option to achieve: visualise both parent-child and tested-by links in 1 hierarchical structure.

You could use "Request a feature" on the left side of [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) to open a new suggestion ticket.